# jquery delete created row from a table

Tags: jquery

i have a button that adds a row to a table. this row contains a text area and radio button and a delete button. how can i delete that created row when i click on the just created delete button

```
<table id="tblAnswers">
  <tr>
    <td><textarea id="Answer1" name="Answer1" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea></td>
      <td> <input name="CorrectAnswer" id="CA" type="radio" value="0" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="AddAnswer" type="button" value="Add Answer now" />

<script>
  var i = 1;
  $("#AddAnswer").click(function () {
    //this is to increment the answer id
    i = i + 1;

    $("#tblAnswers").append('<tr> <td><textarea id="Answer' + i + '" name="Answer' + i + '" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea></td><td> <input name="CorrectAnswer" id="CA" type="radio" value="0" /></td><td><div class="delete" id="bd" style="background-image: url(../Images/delete.png); height: 28px; width: 28px; " onclick="javascript:deleterow();"> </div> </td></tr>');
  });            
</script>
```

i also tried the below but it didn't work

```
<script>
function deleterow(){
  $('table.actionsteps-list').on('click', '.delete', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stops the page jumping to the top
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're duplicating IDs every time you add a row. IDs **must** be unique. And in your deleterow function, shouldn't `table.actionsteps-list` be `#tblAnswers`? I see no table with the class `actionsteps-list`.

Comment: you are absolutely right. i don't know how i missed that. thank you very much. i feel so stupid. filling up my coffee mug right now.

Answer (score 1):

When youre using delegated events (providing a selector for the .click() method) you dont need the deleteRow function in the onclick:

```
 var i = 1;
 $("#AddAnswer").click(function() {

     //this is to increment the answer id
     i = i + 1;


     $("#tblAnswers").append('<tr><td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>');
 });

 $('#tblAnswers').on('click', '.delete', function (e) {
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/svsf0r98/

Also see http://api.jquery.com/on/ under delegated events.

Delegated events are often used when elements will be added dynamically. An approach without delegated events would be:

```
 var i = 1;
 $("#AddAnswer").click(function() {

     //this is to increment the answer id
     i = i + 1;


     $("#tblAnswers").append('<tr><td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td></tr>');
 });

 function deleteRow(button) {
     $(button).closest('tr').remove();
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9u9L84ab/1/